# Appending rows from other sheets to a master sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Literally first time in two decades I've done this and that was even super basic (no pun intended). I have `Sheet1 ("Main Page")` that I am copying data from `("Control Sequences")` based on data entered in `Column B`. I have it sort of working. The issue I will run into is when I copy over the first set of data, then want to bring in another set, the code runs for the whole sheet again and overwrites any tweaks I did previously. I want to be able to bring in a set of data to `Sheet1`, manually skip a couple of rows, type in another value in `column B` below that, re-run the code and append new data in. I'll try to come up with a simpler explanation if this doesn't make sense. Brain is fried right now after 5 hours of VBA absorption :P Here is the code I have so far in its entirety (It's sort of brute force so beware):

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer            'Main Page Sheet Row Number
    Dim n As Integer            'Control Sequences Sheet Row Number
    Dim x As Integer            'Main Page Current Row Number
    Dim y As Integer            'Column Number
    Dim CSrow As Integer        'Current Row
    Dim NextCS As Integer       'Next Control Sequence
    Dim NextCSrow As Integer    'Row To Stop At
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet        'Var
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet        'Var
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Main Page")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Control Sequences")

    y = 2

    'Cycles through the codes in sheet 1
    For i = 2 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).row Step 1
        For n = 2 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).row Step 1
            If ws1.Cells(i, y).Value = ws2.Cells(n, y).Value Then
                x = i
                CSrow = ws2.Cells(n, y).row
                NextCS = ws1.Cells(i, y).Value + 1
                NextCSrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(NextCS, ws2.Range("B1:B200"), 0)
                NextCSrow = NextCSrow - 1
                For CSrow = CSrow To NextCSrow
                    y = y + 1
                    For y = 3 To 7
                        ws1.Cells(x, y).Value = ws2.Cells(CSrow, y).Value
                    Next y
                    ' ws1.Cells(x, 8).Formula = ws2.Cells(CSrow, 8).Formula
                    y = y + 1
                    ws1.Cells(x, y).Value = ws2.Cells(CSrow, y).Value
                    y = y + 2
                    ws1.Cells(x, y).Value = ws2.Cells(CSrow, y).Value
                    x = x + 1
                    y = 2
                Next CSrow
            End If
        Next n
    Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks to anyone for your help and input.

**EDIT 13 FEB 2014**
As mentioned in the comment to the Answer below, I took out the `.End(xlUp)` piece and it worked. I've also changed the body of the writing loop to this:

```
           For CSrow = CSrow To NextCSrow
                ' y = y + 1
                ' For y = 3 To 7
                '     ws1.Cells(x, y).Value = ws2.Cells(CSrow, y).Value
                ' Next y
                ' ws1.Cells(x, 8).Formula = ws2.Cells(CSrow, 8).Formula
                ' y = y + 1
                ' ws1.Cells(x, y).Value = ws2.Cells(CSrow, y).Value
                ' y = y + 2
                ' ws1.Cells(x, y).Value = ws2.Cells(CSrow, y).Value
                ' x = x + 1
                ' y = 2
                ws2.Rows(CSrow).Copy Destination:=ws1.Cells(x, 1)
                x = x + 1
            Next CSrow`
```

I've got the formatting and the formula to copy over without keeping the original reference :D On to part IV... Testing ALL of the Variables and not just 1 ;) I will continue to update this thread with ... well ... updates.

**EDIT 20 FEB 2014**
Here's the complete code as it stands now:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long               'Main Page Sheet Row Number
    Dim j As Long               'Placeholder
    Dim n As Long               'Control Sequences Sheet Row Number
    Dim x As Long               'Main Page Current Row Number
    Dim y As Long               'Column Number
    Dim z As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim CSrow As Long           'Current Row
    Dim NextCS As Long          'Next Control Sequence
    Dim NextCSrow As Long       'Row To Stop At
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet        'Var
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet        'Var
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet        'Var
    Dim ws4 As Worksheet        'Var
    ' Set ws1 = Worksheets("Main Page")
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Control Sequences")
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("Cost 1")
    Set ws4 = Worksheets("Cost 2")

    If ws1.Name = ws2.Name Or ws1.Name = ws3.Name Or ws1.Name = ws4.Name Then
        End
    End If

    y = 2
    z = 10
    a = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, z).End(xlUp).row + 2
    If IsEmpty(ws1.Cells(a, y).Value) Then End

    'Cycles through the codes in sheet 1
    j = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).row
    i = ws1.Cells(j, y).row
    For i = i To j Step 1
        For n = 2 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).row Step 1
            If ws1.Cells(i, y).Value = ws2.Cells(n, y).Value Then
                x = i
                CSrow = ws2.Cells(n, y).row
                NextCS = ws1.Cells(i, y).Value + 1
                NextCSrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(NextCS, ws2.Range("B1:B100"), 0)
                NextCSrow = NextCSrow - 1
                For CSrow = CSrow To NextCSrow
                    ' y = y + 1
                    ' For y = 3 To 7
                    '     ws1.Cells(x, y).Value = ws2.Cells(CSrow, y).Value
                    ' Next y
                    ' ws1.Cells(x, 8).Formula = ws2.Cells(CSrow, 8).Formula
                    ' y = y + 1
                    ' ws1.Cells(x, y).Value = ws2.Cells(CSrow, y).Value
                    ' y = y + 2
                    ' ws1.Cells(x, y).Value = ws2.Cells(CSrow, y).Value
                    ' x = x + 1
                    ' y = 2
                    ws2.Rows(CSrow).Copy Destination:=ws1.Cells(x, 1)
                    x = x + 1
                Next CSrow
            End If
        Next n
    Next i
End Sub
```

I added a check that if the user was on any of the "Template" sheets, the code would just stop. It's a bit brute force, but it gets the job done and it's the only code I have. Maybe if I continue to do this, I'll try to get more "streamlined". :D  Thanks to everyone for their input and help.

Comment: can you somehow show before and after data?

Comment: Hi L42, I can't at this time. Not-public info on it. Once I get it working, I'll come up with a dummy set of data and post it.

Comment: Np. I was just thinking that maybe looping is not the best approach here but if it works for you then its ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it.  Your problem is in the first line of your loop:

```
For i = 2 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).row Step 1
```

Try setting `i` dynamically before the loop begins.  `DIM` another variable `j` for this, then replace the above line with the following:

```
j = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).row
i = ws1.Cells(j, y).End(xlUp).row
For i = i to j Step 1
```

While you're at it, change your row integers to long since there are more rows in a worksheet than integers can handle.

Comment: EXCELLENT! It works! :D Thank you. Now I am going to move on to parts II and III, copying a formula without keeping its original reference (my commented out line) and copying formats of the cells (Fill, Border, etc.) I may be back on if I can't figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: Ummm... It worked the first time and now it's going back and overwriting the changes. ???

Comment: I took out the `.End(xlUp)` because after watching `i` it was going back up to the previous entry and start there. I'll keep testing and update.

Comment: Which `.End(xlUp)` did you remove?  There are two of them in the code I posted ...

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. I think it was the second one. I'll post the finished code above as an EDIT.